# Date and Time on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, timezone

Every time I come on StackOverflow and it's past 8:00 EST, it registers that I came on the next day.  For example, today I logged in and I shows that I viewed the site on Tuesday.  How can I fix this or is this a bug?